# Reading plist in iOS program

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, plist

As i'm beginner `iOS`, i just want to read a simple property list file (`plist`) in my program but it shows me the message "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[ViewController dataFilePath]: unrecognised selector sent to instance 0x15638660'". Kindly help me out where I had issue in program.

```
(.h file)
@interface ViewController : UIViewController {
NSString *listPath;
NSMutableArray *array;
}

- (NSString *) dataFilePath;
- (void) writePlist;
- (void) readPlist;

(.m file)
@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
UIButton *readBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];        readBtn.frame = CGRectMake(110,110,72,39);
[readBtn setTitle:@"Read" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[readBtn addTarget:self            action:@selector(readPlist)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.view addSubview:readBtn];

UIButton *writeBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
writeBtn.frame = CGRectMake(110,210,72,39);
[writeBtn setTitle:@"Write" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[writeBtn addTarget:self  action:@selector(writePlist)  forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.view addSubview:writeBtn];

    [super viewDidLoad];
```

}

```
- (NSString *)DocDirectories {
NSArray *path =                    NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *DocumentDirectory=[path objectAtIndex:0];
return  [DocumentDirectory stringByAppendingString:@"Data.plist"];
```

}

```
- (void)writePlist
{
NSMutableArray *anArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];     
[anArray addObject:@"A"];
[anArray addObject:@"B"];
[anArray writeToFile:[self dataFilePath] atomically:YES];
}

- (void)readPlist
{
NSString *filePath = [self dataFilePath];
if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath]) {
    NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
    NSLog(@"%@\n", array);
    NSLog(@"%@\n",filePath);
   // [array release];    
}
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
}
```

Comment: [anArray writeToFile:[self dataFilePath] atomically:YES];

 replace this with following line 

[anArray writeToFile: dataFilePath atomically:YES];

Comment: "[ViewController dataFilePath]: unrecognised selector" means that your application can't find the function named dataFilePath. Given that you have a NSString defined with this name I think you meant to write [self DocDirectories] in your readPlist function.

Comment: when I write this instruction, error appear "Use of undeclared Identifier 'dataFilePAth'"...

Answer (score 2):

you view controller not has method dataFilePath.

you need to call function DocDirectories.

```
- (void)writePlist
{
    NSMutableArray *anArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];     
    [anArray addObject:@"A"];
    [anArray addObject:@"B"];
    [anArray writeToFile:[self DocDirectories] atomically:YES];
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: @MuhammadZaheer what error you get ? you 'DocDirectories' function will give you path of document directory + Data.plist. Just Log Path so you can check there from finder.

Answer (score 0):

Where is your dataFilePath function?

You should replace the function `dataFilePath` with `DocDirectories`.

try this:

```
- (NSString *)dataFilePath {
    return [self DocDirectories];}
```

Add this function to your `viewController.m`.This issue is the compiler can't find the `function:dataFilePath` when the app is running, because you only decelerate `dataFilePath` in a `.h` file, you should also implement it in `.m` file.

Comment: It should be a comment

Comment: @MidhunMP Sorry,i'm new to stackoverflow.Thanks for reminding

Comment: I replaced function dataFilePath to DocDictionaries but it did not worked so far

Comment: @MuhammadZaheer Follow as my new answer and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Check this

`NSString *plistPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@“Data” ofType:@"plist"];
 NSArray *arrData = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];`

Answer (score 0):

```
Use this  ,you will get

NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Info" ofType:@"plist"]];
    NSLog(@"dictionary = %@", dictionary);
   NSArray *array = [dictionary objectForKey:@"CFBundleSupportedPlatforms"];
   NSLog(@"array = %@", array);
```